# Migration On-premises SQL Server 2008 to Azure vm

Tags: azure, sql-server-2008, azure-virtual-machine, sql-server-migration-assi

- How to identify workload ? testing performance issue ?
- Before migration what i have to check in the VM ?
- after migration any db setting need to change ?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. it's very broad (and contains several questions). Also, it's not a programming question (might be something for the dba stackexchange or serverfault, but not sure if it's on-topic there). And I'm not sure there's a single answer for any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad. Generally, you could work on the Azure VM as usual as you do on your on-premise VM.

Before your migration, you could consider what sizes of Azure VM suitable for your SQL server and OS server version is supported on Azure VM. See the [sizes for Windows virtual machines in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes). Also, you may want to test for SQL Database compatibility issues before you start the migration process referring to [this blog](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2016/01/migrate-from-on-prem-sql-server-to-sql-database/).

You could migrate on-premises SQL Server or SQL Server on Azure VMs to Azure SQL Database using the Data Migration Assistant. Here are the [step-by-step instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-2017) on this tool. You also could use [Azure backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-overview) service to back up Azure IaaS VMs.

More references:

- [How To Move or Migrate SQL Server Workload to Azure SQL Database Cloud Services or Azure VM – All version of SQL Server – Step-By-Step](http://itproguru.com/expert/2015/03/how-to-move-or-migrate-sql-server-workload-to-azure-sql-database-cloud-services-or-azure-vm-all-version-of-sql-server-step-by-step/)
- [Act now! Migrate your customers running Windows Server and SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 to Azure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2018/08/27/migrate-windows-server-sql-server-2008-to-azure/)